# Between Applicative Functor and Monad

Tags: haskell, theory

Is it possible to design an Applicative Functor with a few extra stack manipulation functions `push`, `pop`, and a specialized branching function `ifA :: forall a. f Boolean -> f a -> f a -> f a`, and achieve a model for computation that is equal in expressive power to a Monad? (Can express any program that a Monad can express).

Such a model could be useful for representing computation and maintaining full static analysis.

Such an Applicative Functor might need to be dependently typed (Index Applicative Functor?) with a heterogeneous list. So that it can keep type-safety for `push` and `pop`.

It must be possible somehow. Because a effectful forth program can be viewed as a Monoid.

Comment: You want to make a new `class` or a new `instance`?

Comment: I think it has to be a new ```class``` for type safety. And after a while of thinking about it, I'm tilting towards an Indexed Monoid which seems to be the same thing as a ```Category```.

Comment: Even assembly language can be viewed as a Monoid. It just lacks type safety of the registers and stack, thus the Indexed Monoid to being type safety back.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what do you exactly mean by "expressive power equal to a monad"? (After all, pure lambda calculus is Turing-complete, so you can express any program as a pure function without using monads/applicatives.)  Other than that, your branching function looks similar to [`ArrowChoice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowChoice), and [arrows](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows) were invented precisely to get slightly more static control than general monads can offer.

Comment: @PetrPudlák By expressive power I mean, given any hand writen monadic computation built on top of an unknown context. Can there be another kind of computation also built on top of an unknown context which can be fully reified and hand crafted to perform the same computation as the monadic one. The devil in monads is bind ```>>=``` that forbits full static analysis, and causes Free monads to be slow compared to mtl (continious re-conversions when interpreting binds)

Comment: Given that all programs contain a finite amount of code. Monads themselves seem too powerful an abstraction for representing effectful programs. As bind suggests a continuation of one of possible infinite programs upon unboxing a value from a context. (Just a feeling)

Comment: @PetrPudlák after more thinking. An ```Arrow``` is exactly the level of abstraction I was looking for. I never thought of the two type parameters to an arrow as the type signature of a stack before and after an operation before, but that seems to work out fine. And if you think of ```runFree``` as a compiler for a ```FreeArrow```, the returned computation does not keep re-compiling for each execution of the result (as it would for a ```FreeMonad```). It seems like the perfect solution. If you format your suggestion of using ```arrows``` into an answer, then I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*tl;dr* I believe static [`ArrowChoice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowChoice) is what you're looking for.

---

To elaborate on your interesting question: If we want to have branching computations, we need to be able to pass outputs of one computation as inputs to the following ones.

For `Applicative`s effects can't depend on results, we can imagine that first we perform all effects and then combine all results using a pure computation. Therefore we can represent such a computation with input `i`, output `o` and effect `m` as `m (i -> o)`.

For `Monad`s effects can fully depend on inputs. Thus we can represent computations as `i -> m o`.

If we want to get somewhere in between, we need to parametrise our computations both in input and output. And this is how we get to `Arrow`s, which span the space between `Applicative`s and `Monad`s.

Just like each monad, each arrow `a` gives raise to an `Applicative`. If we fix the input, we can combine two arrows `a i o1` and `a i o2` using `&&&` (and then map the pure part of the result with `>>>` and `arr`).

On the other hand, from each applicative `f` we can define an arrow as `f (i -> o)`. This is the weakest kind of an arrow - it's power is equivalent just to `f`. Such arrows are called *static arrows* and can be recognized by having an isomorphism between `a i o` and `a () (i -> o)` (while we have `a () (i -> o) -> a i o` for any arrow, the opposite exists just for static ones). In other words, the internal effect of the arrow doesn't depend on its input.

At the other end of the spectrum we have [`Kleisli`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Kleisli) arrows. For any monad we can construct arrow `i -> m o`, whose power is equivalent to the monad.

The interesting part is that we can have arrows in between `Monad` and `Applicative`. An nice example, which was the motivation for inventing arrows, is the combination of a [static and dynamic parsers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows#Static_and_dynamic_parsers)¸ The parser has a static part that determines the set of characters the parser is able to consume next, and this static part is computed without having to run the arrow.

---

I guess your idea is to have

```
ifA :: forall a. f Boolean -> f a -> f a -> f a
```

and to pass values to branched computations using stack operations. I'd say that for functional settings it's more natural to embed values into branching. Indeed, the closest operation in [`ArrowChoice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowChoice) (which describes computations that can branch) is

```
(|||) :: a b d -> a c d -> a (Either b c) d
```

---

There is even more general concept - [*generalized arrows*](http://www.megacz.com/berkeley/garrows/). It allows to represent computations that aren't a superset of Haskell (in `Arrow` we can embed any pure function using `arr`), such as bi-directional circuits that can be used for both parsing and pretty-printing.